# Can I apply for a tax refund before leaving Turkey on a train to Sofia?

Tags: trains, borders, turkey, tax-refunds

I have a few items I have the right to apply for a tax refund on, but I leave Turkey on a train to Sofia, not via an airport.

The clerk only told me I can apply for a tax refund at the airport.

In this case, can I apply for a tax refund on a route to Sofia, either at the Halkali station or at the border?

Otherwise, can I just go to the airport and apply for the tax refund without having the flight ticket and hence checking in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You need to show your passport and ticket at the airport. Customs need to ascertain that you are indeed leaving the country with the goods. For exits not by air, there's little you can do in-country. You might be able to catch a Customs officer at the border, one with a stamp in his pocket, and willing to stamp your form. But I've never managed to do that yet...

Comment: Don't the trains have a customs agent when leaving the Schengen area?

Comment: Immigration officers, surely. Customs, maybe. But they're usually more focused on screening goods that enter, rather than do admin tasks for exiting passengers.